# How to get comment based on score/grade in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have question to get comment in table1 based on column1 and column_1_description in table2 using excel

[FirstImage->TheReferenceTableIsFirstSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUFOQ.jpg)

[SecondImage->2ndSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGqfI.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Excel's VLOOKUP function?](https://superuser.com/questions/1226766/how-do-i-use-excels-vlookup-function)

Comment: Are you looking the `COMMENTS` to attach with Cells based on Descriptions or literally the `TEXT` as show in `Col C for TAB 1` based on `descriptions in TAB 2`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula: `=VLOOKUP(B2,I8:J13,2,FALSE)`

[image]

Comment: ,,, I think OP is literally looking to insert some text (shown as Comment in Col C) rather than Descriptions !!

Comment: =if(AE12='Grade Descriptor'!B4 VLOOKUP('Grade Descriptor'!B4,'Grade Descriptor'!B4:H11,2,FALSE)).
i use this formula and return error...

Comment: Try to update your problem and your sample, it's not clearly. You should give more information about your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is converting your grade to ascii code, subtracting out a base amount, then wrapping that with a choose function:

```
=CHOOSE(CODE(B2)-64,"Good","Enough","Fair","Poor","Rejected")
```

Copy the function down. As structure this will show an error for anything other than A, B, C, D, or E.

Good luck